# Add custom HTML to a jQuery FullCalendar cell

Tags: jquery, calendar, rendering, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/).

I want to add some custom HTML to each day-cell.

For example in my case I want to have different background colors based on some logic, display a price in the middle...

[image: sample calendar]

Is there a way to customize the rendering of a cell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will explain how I solved this issue for other people.

I used the [eventAfterRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/) callback. In there I used jQuery to parse the "element" parameter and re-write the html before it is sent to the browser.

Comment: this isn't an answer anyone could possibly use

Comment: because this issue rendering is a huge topic where real code examples are neccesary `eventRender: function(event, element) { element.find('.fc-event-title').append(event.info); } ` - where "info" is a HTML rich field you add in the "event source array - for example

Comment: I uses dayRender since I need to customize whole cell.

Comment: @nute: do you mind updating the answer or question with code?  It will be helpful. I need a similar thing except that i want few 9x9 images to show status for a day. A day can have no status or up to 3 status.

Comment: Sorry this was more than 1.5 years ago, I lost the code and don't really remember...

Answer (score 18):

The way I do this is like Conners indicated:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.find(".fc-event-title").remove();
    element.find(".fc-event-time").remove();
    var new_description =   
        moment(event.start).format("HH:mm") + '-'
        + moment(event.end).format("HH:mm") + '<br/>'
        + event.customer + '<br/>'
        + '<strong>Address: </strong><br/>' + event.address + '<br/>'
        + '<strong>Task: </strong><br/>' + event.task + '<br/>'
        + '<strong>Place: </strong>' + event.place + '<br/>'
    ;
    element.append(new_description);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work the following:   element.find(".fc-event-title").remove();
    element.find(".fc-event-time").remove();

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I dealt with this issue in my application.

In fullcalendar.js, you need to find this:

```
html +=
    "<span class='fc-event-title'>" +
    htmlEscape(event.title || '') +
    "</span>" +
    "</div>";
```

This is where the content of the cell is created.

I wanted to have the time of the event on the right side of the cell, so:

```
html +=
    "<span class='fc-event-title'><div style='float:right'>" + moment(event.start).format('hh:mm a') + "</div>" +
    htmlEscape(event.title || '') +
    "</span>" +
    "</div>";
```

I am using the momentjs library to format the time.

Now, you can add whatever you want to the calendar cell content, and use standard html to format it.

Comment: Modifying the plugin file itself is usually a huge no-no. It breaks upgradeability in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20197066/4866763) provided a very simple method that worked for me:

```
cell.prepend('<span class="selector">' + ReturnCellNumber(cellDay,cellMonth,cellYear) + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been using [Gjermund Dahl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24563491/6068536)'s answer above until I made some tweaks to my calendar.  With this method I can make the formatting different for different views.  When the calendar uses lists and timelines, removing the title class in a blanket action on render produces varied results across different views.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {

    // explore the element object
    // console.log(element);        

    // edit list view titles
    // during the render, check for the list class to be in the element
    // if there is a fc-list-class then we are going to make our changes accordingly
    if( element[0].className === 'fc-list-item' ){
        // create your new name
        var x = '<strong>' + event.title + ' ' + model + '</strong><br/>' +  cust;
        // create array to be added to element                   
        var update = { innerHTML: x };
        // replace element with update value in the right place    
        $.extend( true, element[0].childNodes[2], update ); 
    }

    // edit timeline view titles
    // during the render, check for the timeline class to be in the element
    // if there is a fc-timeline-event then we are going to make our changes accordingly
    if( element[0].className.indexOf( 'fc-timeline-event' ) === 0 ) {
        var x = '<span class="fc-title">' + '<strong>'
        + customer + '</strong><br/>'+ new + ' ' + make + ' ' + model + '</span>';
        // create array to be added to element                   
        var update = { innerHTML: x };
        // replace element with update value in the right place    
        $.extend( true, element[0].childNodes[0].firstChild, update );
    } 
}
```

Note the different places that are appended in the two views.  You will have to explore your element object to review where you want your new content.  You can also choose where to make this change with more control.  Change the innerHTML, or the innerText, or whatever your heart desires.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  eventRender: function (event, element) {
            let new_description = '<div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title '+event.className+'">' + event.title + '</span>'
                + '<span class="fc-time">' + event.start.format('hh:mma') + '-' + event.end.format('hh:mma') + '</span>'
                + '<span class="' + event.statusCss + '">' + event.status + '</span></div>'
            ;
            element.html(new_description);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can get this:

```
    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
            cell.append('<div style="text-align:center; background-color:blue; color:#fff;padding:2px 0;margin-top:20px;">Add Your Text!</div>');
           },
```

For more info : [Add custom HTML to a jQuery FullCalendar cell](https://therichpost.com/fullcalendar-add-custom-text-to-date-if-there-is-not-event)

Comment: That was more than 6 years ago I don’t remember 