# FullCalendar Month view showing incorrect time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, momentjs

When I toggle between Month, BasicWeek, and AgendaDay views on my FullCalendar control, the event time is displayed incorrectly on the Month view. (e.g. correct event time = 4:00pm, but the Month calendar displays 12:21p)

The configuration and data are the same (since this is on the same page), only the type of calendar view has changed.

Here is the demonstration code:
http://jsfiddle.net/wloescher/1opdu0yc/7/

External Resources:
jQuery 2.1.0
Bootstrap 3.2.0
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.2/fullcalendar.min.js
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.2/fullcalendar.min.css

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        timeFormat: 'h:mmt',
        eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
            CalendarAddItemIcons();
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.popover({
                title: event.title,
                placement: 'auto',
                html: true,
                trigger: 'hover',
                animation: 'true',
                content: event.desc,
                container: 'body'
            });
        },
        events: [{title: 'PlaceHolder',start: new Date(2013, 1, 1)},{id: 562, title: 'Sample Idea', start: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/562', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus2', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Creation <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 550, title: 'School Shopping - How to make sure you are getting the best bargains', start: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/550', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 654, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [1 of 10]', start: '2001-09-05T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/654', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 655, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [2 of 10]', start: '2001-10-03T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/655', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 656, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [3 of 10]', start: '2001-11-07T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/656', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 657, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [4 of 10]', start: '2001-12-05T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/657', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 658, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [5 of 10]', start: '2002-01-02T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/658', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 659, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [6 of 10]', start: '2002-02-06T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/659', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 660, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [7 of 10]', start: '2002-03-06T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/660', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 661, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [8 of 10]', start: '2002-04-03T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/661', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 662, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [9 of 10]', start: '2002-05-01T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/662', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 556, title: 'Sample Blog Post', start: '2015-07-28T12:06:57', url: '/ContentEdit/556', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus4', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: Ready to Publish / Approved <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 557, title: 'Sample Newsletter', start: '2015-07-28T12:21:00', url: '/ContentEdit/557', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 675, title: 'Test Item for Word Count', start: '2015-08-07T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/675', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemOther ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Infographic <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 663, title: 'Monthly Newsletter Series [10 of 10]', start: '2015-08-11T16:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/663', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemEmail ContentItemStatus5', desc: 'Type: Newsletter <br/> Status: Complete <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 602, title: 'Fall Vacation Destinations', start: '2015-08-13T14:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/602', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus3', desc: 'Type: Article <br/> Status: In Review <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 601, title: 'Summer Vacation Tips', start: '2015-08-13T17:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/601', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemOther ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Infographic <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 691, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [1 of 10]', start: '2015-08-19T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/691', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 692, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [2 of 10]', start: '2015-08-21T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/692', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 693, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [3 of 10]', start: '2015-08-24T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/693', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 694, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [4 of 10]', start: '2015-08-26T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/694', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 695, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [5 of 10]', start: '2015-08-28T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/695', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 696, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [6 of 10]', start: '2015-08-31T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/696', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 677, title: 'Something Blue', start: '2015-09-01T11:56:00', url: '/ContentEdit/677', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemOther ContentItemStatus3', desc: 'Type: Press Release <br/> Status: In Review <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 697, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [7 of 10]', start: '2015-09-02T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/697', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 698, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [8 of 10]', start: '2015-09-04T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/698', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 699, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [9 of 10]', start: '2015-09-07T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/699', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 700, title: 'of Blog Posts Series [10 of 10]', start: '2015-09-09T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/700', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus1', desc: 'Type: Blog Post <br/> Status: In Planning <br/> Assigned: Tandy '},{id: 650, title: 'Christmas Decorating Tips', start: '2015-10-31T10:00:00', url: '/ContentEdit/650', textColor:'#000000', color: ' #efefef ', className: 'ContentItemWeb ContentItemStatus2', desc: 'Type: Article <br/> Status: In Creation <br/> Assigned: Tandy '}],
        eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
            //Start calendar update
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'WebServices/CalendarWebService.asmx/MoveCalendarEvent',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    itemId: event.id,
                    dateTarget: event.start
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (msg) {
                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                    //alert(event.title + ' has been rescheduled.');    
                }
            });
            //end calendar update   
        }
    });

    function CalendarAddItemIcons() {
        //add calender content item icons
        $(".ContentItemFacebook .fc-content .fc-time").html("<i class='fa fa-facebook' style='font-size:16px;color:#3e56a0;'></i><br/>" +                   $(".ContentItemFacebook .fc-content .fc-time").html() + "<br/>");
        $(".ContentItemTwitter .fc-content .fc-time").html("<i class='fa fa-twitter' style='font-size:16px;color:#659fcd;'></i><br/>" +     $(".ContentItemTwitter  .fc-content .fc-time").html() + "<br/>");
        $(".ContentItemEmail .fc-content .fc-time").html("<i class='fa fa-envelope' style='font-size:16px;color:#3e56a0;'></i><br/>" + $(".ContentItemEmail  .fc-content .fc-time").html() + "<br/>");
        $(".ContentItemWeb .fc-content .fc-time").html("<i class='fa fa-file-text' style='font-size:16px;color:#3e56a0;'></i><br/>" + $(".ContentItemWeb .fc-content .fc-time").html() + "<br/>");
        $(".ContentItemGooglePlus  .fc-content .fc-time").html("<i class='fa fa-google-plus' style='font-size:16px;color:#dd4b39;'></i><br/>" +  $(".ContentItemGooglePlus .fc-content .fc-time").html() + "<br/>");
     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Probl, you already notice it, but the problem appears only when you modify your event content via `CalendarAddItemIcons`. Maybe you can modify the event on `EventRender` as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702058/add-custom-html-to-a-jquery-fullcalendar-cell

Comment: eventAfterAllRender event has to be used, because CalendarAddItemIcons relies on the content of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in the "CalendarAddItemIcons" function. The existing code added an icon to the existing HTML, which could also be accomplished using the jQuery .prepend function.

Code changed to the following, and issue has been resolved.

I don't know why this fixed the issue, nor why this only affected only the Month view.

```
function CalendarAddItemIcons() {
    //add calender content item icons
    $(".ContentItemFacebook .fc-content .fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-facebook' style='font-size:16px;color:#3e56a0;'></i><br />");
    $(".ContentItemTwitter .fc-content .fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-twitter' style='font-size:16px;color:#659fcd;'></i><br />");
    $(".ContentItemEmail .fc-content .fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-envelope' style='font-size:16px;color:#3e56a0;'></i><br />");
    $(".ContentItemWeb .fc-content .fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-file-text' style='font-size:16px;color:#3e56a0;'></i><br />");
    $(".ContentItemGooglePlus  .fc-content .fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-google-plus' style='font-size:16px;color:#dd4b39;'></i><br />");
}
```