# How to create calendar view with Laravel - Blade

Tags: php, laravel, calendar, laravel-blade

I need to create calendar with blade (laravel 5.1) but nowhere I dont find something like that so please help me...

First, I have this database:

etc.

OFFERS TABLE

```
  id           price         article_id                    date
    1             230            1                           01-02-2016
    2             245            1                           01-02-2016
    3             230            1                           02-02-2016
    4             231            1                           02-02-2016
    5             233            1                           02-02-2016
    6             244            1                           03-02-2016
    7             276            1                           04-02-2016
```

etc...

How I want to get for every date in etc. - February (1 . - 29.) highest price for every date and with this data to create calendar table view.

Screenshoot: [image]

So how to create html table with data with Blade templating engine? Is it possible ?

I create function offer in Laravel controler but this return me all offers and its not a problem , problem is how to create html calendar table with blade in view...

```
public function offers($id)
    {
        $offers = Offer::where('article_id', $id)->latest()->get();

        return $offers;
    }
```

Comment: I would use something like FullCalendar to help you display this information. http://fullcalendar.io/ https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar

Comment: I know that tool, but I need to create this with blade... Is it possible to do?

Comment: Why do you have to use Blade? You could make it manually with an HTML table using `foreach` loops that load the days in the month in then place them on the correct cell.

Comment: ok, but with blade I easily can add data from database - laravel on backend... can you show me how to create with html and I will try to make it with blade correctly

Comment: You could easily add data from your database with full calendar, which would be far easier. You could even modify the cell to give you a custom layout like you are after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702058/add-custom-html-to-a-jquery-fullcalendar-cell. Making this yourself would be a bit of a b*tch and involve a fair bit of logic to make it dynamic

Comment: I will try with fullCalendar io... thanks for this , I really dont know that can be easily to create custom layout... Do you have more examples of customlayout of fullCalendar ?

Comment: The fullCalendar is just a jquery calendar that is implemented into your blade template like any other piece of html/js/css code.