# How to use custom fields in jquery FullCalendar?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I am new to ajax/jquery in gerneral and found jquery's fullcalendar made by Adam Shaw. This looks like exactly what i need.

I found a few tutorials on how to get it to read from a php/mysql setup which works fine if I use exactly the same field names they are telling me (start, end, etc). What I am wondering is how do I tell it to use my own date fields as start and end dates. I also want to add some extra fields like comments (i already have a calendar database with data in it that I want to use without restructuring it as other things use the same database).

Field name examples:

- startDate
- endDate
- comments
- reoccuring

If someone could let me know how to tell it to use the custom date fields as well as displaying other custom fields that would be awesome.

The current script I have is:
The jquery/ajax currently using

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate(),
                m = date.getMonth(),
                y = date.getFullYear();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'Today',
                    month: 'Month',
                    week: 'Week',
                    day: 'Day'
                },

                events: "../calendar/internal/events.php"
          });
    });
</script>
```

events.php

```
    <?php
     $json = array();
     $requete = "SELECT * FROM internal_calendar ORDER BY id";
     try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendarDB', 'root', 'securepassword');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        exit('Unable to connect to database.');
     }
     $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
     echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
jAC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before making json format of your result, you need to do some stuff to make acceptable for fullcalendar as event.

```
$result = $resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$events = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $events[] = array (
        'start' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['startDate'])),
        'end' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['endDate'])),
        'comments' => $row['comments'],
        'reoccuring' =>  $row['reoccuring'],
        'title' => 'Set title here', // Set comment here to show in event block.
    )

}

echo json_encode($events);
```

event's title property is used to show data in event block in fullcalendar. You can set comments as title.

```
'title' => $row['comments']
```

That's it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much @Chintan-Mirani - Do you know how I would expose my comments so they display in the calendar event block as well?

Comment: @jAc I have edited answer to show comments in event block. Title property is to show data in event block.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself enough. Is there a way to add a custom field to show up under the title. So still have the title but so the comments as well?

Comment: You can merge (concat) title with comments. You also can set your customized html code containing your data.

Comment: I tried that but it is not rendering the html. For example if I do a <br/> it shows up as <br/> not a new line. Any thoughts to that?

Comment: I figured it out using the help from this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702058/add-custom-html-to-a-jquery-fullcalendar-cell comment by Gjermund Dahl. Thanks again for all your help Chintan!