# fullcalendar Month View Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to use [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) in my new project but I can't find any information on how to do what I want. Has anyone done something similar or have any idea on how I can achieve this? My aim is to have a Month View of the calendar like this:

[image: calendar month view]

However, what ever I've tried I couldn't make the 2 slots visible in the Month View.

Answer (score 0):

What is displayed within those 2 slots? You will probably have to make your own custom view for this.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views

Comment: Have you any more detailed documentation or tutorial about the custom-views ?? because I've already seen this but can't figure what I've to do to make it !! Thanks :D

Comment: You should check this link out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702058/add-custom-html-to-a-jquery-fullcalendar-cell

Incase you just want to edit the html, this would be a good solution.
If you can tell me in more detail what exactly you want to achieve, please let me know!

Comment: Actually I'm trying to make a calendar for staff leaves submissions ! So the calendar would be Month agenda that have at a maximum of 2 events per day per person ( the first for the morning and the second for the afternoon) so if the staff clicks on the first he would submit a request for a morning leave and if he clicks on the second it would be for an afternoon leave and if he clicks on booth he would submit for a day leave. Hope this explanation will be helpful :D